# Best service on AWS for collecting user action data

Tags: amazon-web-services, analytics

What is the best service on AWS for gathering user action data? Metrics like the number of sessions, unique sessions, duration of sessions, user's search, how are they responding to the value of real-time recommendations, and where do they land.
I'm using Amplify for deploying my application.
So far I thought about extracting these metrics from CloudWatch but I was wondering if maybe there is a service that will help with this. I also looked into AWS pinpoint but I don't think that also is the right tool for what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS Cloudwatch is most likely the best service for this, since it either has the information already or you can push custom metrics in.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion on how I can extract data I need from Cloudwatch logs?
I read this one articel  but I wa wondering if you know any better way.
https://praveshchhabra.medium.com/data-analysis-on-aws-using-quicksight-8ca033dd3563

Comment: I have not tried to do that so I can't recommend anything. Cloudwatch is the best source for the data, analysis someone else will have to help with.

Answer (score 0):

Here is AWS support answer to this question:

> I would like to inform you that you can Amazon Cloudwatch logs to log
> user activity on your application, you can refer to the following
> documentation for the same.
>
> [+]
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/WhatIsCloudWatchLogs.html
> CloudWatch Logs enables you to centralize the logs from all of your
> systems, applications, and AWS services that you use, in a single,
> highly scalable service. You can then easily view them, search them
> for specific error codes or patterns, filter them based on specific
> fields, or archive them securely for future analysis. CloudWatch Logs
> enables you to see all of your logs, regardless of their source, as a
> single and consistent flow of events ordered by time, and you can
> query them and sort them based on other dimensions, group them by
> specific fields, create custom computations with a powerful query
> language, and visualize log data in dashboards.
>
> You can also consider using Amazon Timestream to store and analyze
> events on your application. You can then ingest this data in
> Quicksight to visualize and build dashboard.
>
> [+]
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/timestream/latest/developerguide/what-is-timestream.html#what-is.use-cases
> Amazon TimeStream is a fast, scalable, and serverless time series
> database service for IoT and operational applications that makes it
> easy to store and analyze trillions of events per day up to 1,000
> times faster and at as little as 1/10th the cost of relational
> databases.